# How to end an express.js / node POST response?

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to just stop the post request after I've saved a document to the DB, ie:

```
app.post('/blah'), function(req,res){ 
//my code does a bunch of stuff

res.what do i put here to tell the client browser to just... stop the POST
}
```

At the moment im simply using `res.redirect('back')` which works, but the page refresh is totally arbitrary and i would prefer it didnt happen. I had a go at `res.end();` but that sends the client to a blank page...

Thanks in advance.

***edit:***

I dont think i made myself clear enough in what im doing sorry.

Perhaps its bad practice but this is whats happening:

1. POST initiates database save function
2. Browser sits around waiting for a response
3. When its good and ready, the obj is saved to the DB, then a callback triggers a *NowJS* function, which adds the item to the view(for everyone)

I did it this way to be non-blocking( so i thought)

Comment: res.end() or with res.json if you are returning some json response.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use `res.end` and pass in a string that you want to be sent to the client:

```
res.end('It worked!');
```

Alternatively, you could [render a view](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) and then end the response:

```
res.render('blah.jade');
res.end();
```

All that said, redirecting the client is actually the best practice. It makes it so that when they hit the back button in their browser, they can move back seamlessly without getting any "POST required" popups or the like. This is the POST/redirect pattern and you can read more about it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get.

Comment: You don't need res.end following res.render. The POST/redirect pattern is the way to go -- unless the POST is via JSON or XMLHttpRequest. You can check for both of those, and if the request is successful, just send res.json(200) or res.send(200) (or some other more RESTful 200-range response code).

Comment: res.end('It worked!'); brings the user to a page that reads 'It worked!'

Comment: I have the same question. I dont want it to rediect to any other page or refresh the current page. Is there a way to do it? res.redirect('back') or res.end() are both either refresh or send the user to another page. I want to keep it on the same page.

Answer (score 7):

For future reference, you can also do:

```
res.redirect('back');
```

Basically this just redirects the browser back to the screen the request came from, in other words "refreshing" it. It's hacky and I wish there was a better way, but it works.

Comment: Why is this considered hacky? It seems to do exactly what it implies and seems like a good way to create the effect of a post request that doesn't take you somewhere new.

Comment: You answered your own question -- "create the effect ... that doesn't take you somewhere new." A better non-hacky solution would just do what the OP wants without having to "create the effect" of it. To be clear, I use this method in my own projects, so I didn't mean "hacky" negatively necessarily, just to insinuate there should be (might be) a better way.

Answer (score 5):

While you can use the underlying `end` method borrowed from Node's http module, Express.js has its own `send` method that calls `end` when appropriate:

```
/**
 * Send a response.
 *
 * Examples:
 *
 *     res.send(new Buffer('wahoo'));
 *     res.send({ some: 'json' });
 *     res.send('<p>some html</p>');
 *     res.send(404, 'Sorry, cant find that');
 *     res.send(404);
 *
 * @param {Mixed} body or status
 * @param {Mixed} body
 * @return {ServerResponse}
 * @api public
 */
res.send = function(body){
  .
  .
  .

  // respond
  this.end(head ? null : body);
  return this;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use --> res.status(204).send(); inside the post request

```
if(err) {

   console.log(err);

} else {

   res.status(204).send();

}
```

Comment: The HTTP 204 No Content success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded, but that the client doesn't need to go away from its current page. A 204 response is cacheable by default. An ETag header is included in such a response.

The common use case is to return 204 as a result of a PUT request, updating a resource, without changing the current content of the page displayed to the user. If the resource is created, 201 Created is returned instead. If the page should be changed to the newly updated page, the 200 should be used instead.
From: MDN web docs - 204 No Content

Answer (score 2):

If you could modify your client side code to make the post request via AJAX, you could simply use res.end().

The problem here is that when the browser makes a POST request (not via AJAX), it no longer cares about the current page. It is expecting a new page, so it will load a new page. This is purely with the browser, and I do not believe there is currently a way for you to work around it.

Overall, you should just use an AJAX POST request if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The client browser is waiting for a response. So why not give it one with something like `res.send('<p>Thank you</p>');` or a nice rendered view?

The reason `res.end()` sends the client to a blank page is that you aren't giving the client anything to display.

Comment: What im actually doing is triggering NowJS to asynch'ly update the page as well as update my database. So the page has already been updated with the new content, the browser just doesnt know it.

I have updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to end the express routing without routing to new page or what ever the mess express want you not to stay on the current page although you have your own reason is to use window.stop, for example a form, you use javascript to handle the submission, the timeout should be enough to ensure the data is send as POST method.

```
document.myform.mysubmit.click()
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        window.stop() 
    }, 3000);
```