# Express js res.redirect() from mongoose callback not working

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

What I'm trying to do here is,

from `/expense/new` page submitting `POST` request to `/expense/newPost`

on Expressjs, handling this way

```
app.post('/expense/newPost', function(req, res) { ...
```

continue, using `mongoose` I validate the collection as

```
tmpExp = new Expense(req.body);

tmpExp.validate(function(err) {
  if(err || !isValidForm) {
    req.session.form.errField =  _.extend(req.session.form.errField, (err.errors || err ));
    req.session.rePop = req.body;
    res.redirect('/expense/new');
  } else {
    console.log('now saving') // successfully logs here.
    tmpExp.save(expPost, function(err2, savedDoc) {
      if(err2) {
        req.session.flash = { 
            global: true
          , css: "error"
          , message: "Internal Server Error"
        }
        res.redirect('/expense/new');
      } else {
        res.redirect('/expense/new?success=' + savedDoc.bill_id);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

for shake of clearity I removed some of the validation code.

**Now the problem is, after submitting the POST request by browser data is successfully saved in mongodb but browser not redirect and just waiting for response from server**

Comment: If you look in Chrome's network inspector, can you see any Location header? Is anything else earlier in the code maybe already sending data?

Comment: @loganfsmyth In Chrome's network inspector request on `newPost` displays pending for 2-3 minutes and then `No data recieved` page display(I mean connection is closed by browser due to no data recieved during predefined time)

Comment: @loganfsmyth sorry actually server closed the connection without sending any data, as seeen on chrome's `No data recieved` page. `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data`

Comment: You don't have any `res.end()` calls anywhere else in your handler do you? It may be too much to post in here, but if you are up for posting your whole handler in a JSFiddle or something, then that could be useful.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I think you don't need to call `res.end()` after `res.redirect()` see comment on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107226/how-do-i-end-an-expressjs-node-post-response/9110473#9110473

Comment: Totally right, I wanted to make sure you weren't calling it before `res.redirect` somewhere, since so much of the code is missing it is hard to guess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18702/discussion-between-hitesh-chavda-and-loganfsmyth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your save callback is not passed in properly.

```
tmpExp.save(expPost, function(err2, savedDoc) {
```

should be:

```
tmpExp.save(function(err2, savedDoc) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming verification code is the only thing you stripped from this file, `res` is not defined. I'd suggest you just return Error or null and do the remaining logic in the parent function, where res is likely to be present. This also is generally a good practice because your model will be reusable (no path parts in the model)

Comment: No, this isnt in model its in `app.post('/expense/newPost', function(req, res) {`