# Nodejs page not redirecting after POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms

My problem is similar enough to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107226/how-to-end-an-express-js-node-post-response) but also different and the answers aren't working for me.

I have a form to post and I need to display a message on the page whether it entered the data to the database successfully or not.  So I have:

```
app.post('/add_new', upload.single('image'), function add_new(req, res, err)

{
   var image = req.body.image; 
   // do some checks and try to insert
    if (err){
        res.render('page_name',{images:images, message:'There was an error'})
    }
    else{
     images.push(image);
     res.render('page_name',{images:images, message: 'Success'})}
    }
}
```

The error/success messages are handled on the client side.

My problem is that it doesn't actually complete the post.  It renders the page with the error/success message correctly but the URL looks like 'my_site.com/add_new', and if the user refreshes the page for any reason, it sends that 'form resubmission' alert, which causes problems.  I need it to go back to 'my_site.com' and display the message.

I have found that doing

```
res.redirect('back')
```

returns to the correct page but obviously doesn't display the message.
I have noticed a few answers recommending

```
res.end('Success')
```

but that just displays a white page with the word 'Success' - I don't know how anyone thinks that's an acceptable solution!

**EDIT:**
Following Vinay's answer, my code now reads like:

```
app.post('/add_new', upload.single('image'), function add_new(req, res, err)

{
   var image = req.body.image; 
   // do some checks and try to insert
    if (err){
        req.session.msg='error adding';
        res.redirect('page_name');
    }
    else{
     images.push(image);
     req.session.msg='success';
     res.redirect('page_name');
    }
}
```

and this to get the page:

```
app.get('/page_name', is_logged_in, function(req, res) {
    if(req.session.msg){
        res.render('page_name', {images: images, user:req.user, message: req.session.msg});
        setTimeout(req.session.msg="", 4000);
    }
    else{
        res.render('page_name', {images: images, user:req.user, message:''});
    }
});
```

But I am still finding that the error message persists when the page is refreshed.  Have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

currently you are doing this

```
if (err){
    res.render('page_name',{images:images, message:'There was an error'})
}
else{
 images.push(image);
 res.render('page_name',{images:images, message: 'Success'})}
}
```

you are getting url like this to 'my_site.com/add_new', **which is correct** rendering means your are loading/rendering html page to particular route which is '/add_new'.

There may be a two solution

**1st solution**

```
res.redirect('/?msg=' + string);
```

and on home page

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  if(req.query.msg){
      // display error message
  }else{
      // else do not display error
   }
});
```

**2nd solution**

```
req.session.msg = "message here";
res.redirect('/');
```

and on home page you can do like this.

```
if(req.session.msg){ 
    //display error message here
    // after displaying msg in that last this 
    setTimeout(req.session.msg="", 3000); // this will clear a session after 3 seconds, so next time it will not display the msg.
  } else {
    //or display home page without error.
  };
```

you can use one of them.

Comment: Thanks very much for this Vinay.  I gave both solutions a try and both were definitely an improvement.  The second solution is closest to what I need although I'd love if the error message would go away when the user refreshes the page.  Even so, you've helped me out a lot!

Comment: for that you need clear a session req.session.msg = ""; so what you can do that after loading a page you can clear a seesion after 3 second so message will not display next time if page is reloaded. check out my update solution.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  I have updated my question with my new code so I'd be very grateful if you could point out if I misinterpreted your answer.